# How to show that the general orthogonal group $O(n,1)$ has four components?

Tags: matrices

Define a bilinear form on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ by $(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_iy_i-x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$, the general orthogonal group $O(n,1)$ is defined to be $\left\{B\in GL(n+1,\mathbb R)\mid(Bx,By)=(x,y),\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^{n+1}\right\}$, where $(x,y)=\langle x,gy\rangle,\, g=\operatorname{diag}\{1,\cdots,1,-1\}$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual Euclidean inner product. Thus $B\in O(n,1)\Leftrightarrow B^tgB=g$. This is shown as a result in Brian C. Hall's *"Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations"*, but I hope to get a proof that $O(n,1)$ has four components.

Comment: Not a full proof, but the idea is that the time-like vectors (those withe neagtive length) form an open double cone which has two components. Time-like vectors are always mapped to time-like vectors. Now one has to observe that there are isometries that preserve "causality", i.e., which map each of the cone's two components into itself. And there are isometries that do not.  Moreover, there cannot be a continuous path from a causality-perserving isometry to a causality-reversing isometry because such a path would contain an isometry that maps a time-like vector to a space-like one.

Comment: So causality-preserving/reversing splits the orthogonal group into two parts that are not connected to each other. An the determinant splits each of the two parts into further two. So one can show that there are at least 4 components by constructing an explicit isometry in each of the four sets defined by orientation and causality. contains a

Comment: But I have no argument at the moment why there should not be more than 4 components.

Comment: Wouldn't $O(n,\Bbb R)$ mean $O(n)$, not $O(n,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

Denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ by $\{e_1,\ldots,e_{n+1}\}$. $O(n,1)$ has four connected components:

- $\{B\in O(n,\mathbb R):\det(B)=1,\ (Be_{n+1},e_{n+1})>0\}$,
- $\{B\in O(n,\mathbb R):\det(B)=1,\ (Be_{n+1},e_{n+1})<0\}$,
- $\{B\in O(n,\mathbb R):\det(B)=-1,\ (Be_{n+1},e_{n+1})>0\}$,
- $\{B\in O(n,\mathbb R):\det(B)=-1,\ (Be_{n+1},e_{n+1})<0\}$.

In fact, each member of $O(n,1)$ can be expressed as
\begin{align}
B&=\begin{bmatrix}Q\\ &1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_n+\left(\sqrt{1+c^2}-1\right)uu^T&cu\\ cu^T&\sqrt{1+c^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}I_n\\ &t\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
Q\left[I_n+\left(\sqrt{1+c^2}-1\right)uu^T\right]&tcQu\\ cu^T&t\sqrt{1+c^2}
\end{bmatrix}\tag{0}
\end{align}
where $t\in\{1,-1\},\,Q\in O(n),\,c\in\mathbb R$ and $u$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb R^n$. The sign of $(Be_{n+1},e_{n+1})$ is $-t$ while $\det(B)=t\det(Q)$. With this characterisation of $B$, the path-connectedness of each of the four aforementioned sets is evident.

To prove that $B$ can be written in the above form, let us partition $B$ as $\pmatrix{X&v\\ w^t&\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is a scalar and $X,v,w$ are matrices or vectors of appropriate sizes. The equation $B^tgB=g$ can then be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&X^tX=I+ww^t,\tag{1}\\
&X^tv=\lambda w,\tag{2}\\
&\lambda^2=1+\|v\|^2.\tag{3}
\end{align}
By $(3)$, $\lambda$ is never zero. Moreover, the RHS of $(1)$ is positive definite. Therefore $X$ is nonsingular and $(2),(3)$ implies that $v$ and $w$ are either both zero or both nonzero.

If $v=w=0$, clearly $X$ is a real orthogonal matrix and $\lambda=\pm1$. Therefore $B$ takes the form of $(0)$. Now suppose $v,w\ne0$. The positive definite square root of $I+ww^t$ is $I+\left(\sqrt{\|w\|^2+1}-1\right)\frac{ww^t}{\|w\|^2}$. Therefore $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
X=Q\left[I+\left(\sqrt{\|w\|^2+1}-1\right)\frac{ww^t}{\|w\|^2}\right]\tag{4}
$$
for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$. Substitute this into $(2)$, we obtain
$$
\left[I+\left(\sqrt{\|w\|^2+1}-1\right)\frac{ww^t}{\|w\|^2}\right]Q^tv=\lambda w\tag{5}
$$
and hence
$$
Q^tv=tw\tag{6}
$$
for some nonzero scalar $t$. Substitute this back into $(5)$, we obtain $(t\sqrt{\|w\|^2+1})w=\lambda u$. Hence
$$
\lambda=t\sqrt{\|w\|^2+1}.\tag{7}
$$
Since $\|v\|=\|Q^tv\|=\|tw\|$, by $(3)$ we have $t^2(\|w\|^2+1)=1+t^2\|w\|^2$, i.e. $t=\pm1$. Now, $w=cu$ for some scalar $c$ and unit vector $u$. Then by $(4),(6)$ and $(7)$, we see that $B=\pmatrix{X&v\\ w^t&\lambda}$ takes the form of $(0)$.